# NSNotification Center only works in second time? TabbarController to NavigationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

Scenario i have two view controllers: Tabcontroller and Viewcontroller. In the first i define my post notification and in the second i added an observer with a receive method.

**On my tabcontroller (sender):**

```
-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RestartBtn" object:self userInfo:@{@"isHidden": @"YES"}];

}
```

**On the viewcontoller (receiver):**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"HallOfFameView");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"RestartBtn" object:nil];

}
-(void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {

    NSLog(@"%@",[notification name]);
    _restartbutton.hidden=YES;
    NSLog(@"%@",notification.userInfo[@"isHidden"]);
    NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notificationCenter removeObserver:self name:@"RestartBtn" object:nil];
    }
```

When i click on my tabbaritem it will push a view controller and it will print "HallOfFameView" and i believe that will register the observer but is not executing the receive notification method at first time only on second time. For example when i click on tabbar item ("Home"), it will execute the receive notification method.

Why is not working on first time? and why it will work when have already exit from the viewcontroller where i'll expect to work (which is where i add my observer).

Comment: Below my answer works?

Answer (score 2):

1. You're right. The view controller is registering for the notification, but it doesn't receive the notification. The notification was already fired by the tab bar controller before the view controller came into existence and registered itself.
2. The tab bar controller is posting that notification for every tab that gets selected. So when you tap on another tab bar item, the notification gets posted and by now the view controller *is* in existence and receives it.

It looks like what you're trying to do is pass information from the tab bar controller to the view controller. There's probably a better way to do that.

If you're using storyboards then the tab bar controller will be using a segue to move to the view controller scene. You could look into overriding this method on your tab bar controller: `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` that will give you a chance to set a property on the 'destination view controller'.

Comment: Thanks i understand now. In fact, you first must have to add a observer and then you will post information. Without observers the message will be gone. Conclusion with NSnotifications i always must to add observer before post notification. Is not good for future you will need always to loaded your view to add in first place a observer...

Comment: Yes, and you can't even be sure how long the view will take to load. You could look at overriding this method on the tab bar controller. -(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController .... you can check to see if viewController is the class of view controller that you want and then set a property there. Different ways to do it.

Comment: Yes i believe prepareForSegue will not work, the better way it seems to be like you said to use ` -(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`. Do you agree? if yes,you may edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put your add observer coding in viewWillAppear method and also remove observer in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"RestartBtn" object:nil];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receiveNotification:) name:@"RestartBtn" object:nil];
}
```

Comment: Not working for me..  I used a similar approach inside on receiveNotification method, but i believe that my problem is that i'm not using NSNotification properly since that i must to define a observer in first place and then post notifications to that observer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help but i already use -(void) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController instead. and it works fine for me!